# wkhtmltopdf segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, wkhtmltopdf, gentoo

I'm trying to get wkhtmltopdf to work on my Gentoo server.

Gentoo version : 1.6.14 - x86_64

So I downloaded the 64 bits last version and untar. Set chmod. Tried to move it and ln in /usr/local/bin

```
Segmentation fault
```

Tried with the original executable directly, same. Tried to install dependencies `urw-fonts`, `libXext` and `libXrender` through emerge, as far as I can tell it installed well but doesn't change anything - same error. Tried with the 32 bits version as well - same error. No details, just this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

[EDIT] It's even worse than that ! Launching

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
```

Gives the same error !

Comment: What for error do you get?...

Comment: I specified in my message, no error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install wkhtmltopdf with ease through portage
`emerge -av wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: Nope, not working. My portage tree is not up to date at all, and I can't change it since it's a custom release from our provider. We started a server migration, this server is simply too old. Thanks for answering, I will accept the answer since there are no others and I really think it's impossible with this server.